# How do I loop through the children of an element I found using Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, loops, element, children

I've found the element I'm looking for by link text and now I would like to print the names of all its children. The problem is that there are other links that use the same class all over the page and I only want the children of this one.

I start by finding the one I want with:
   driver.find_element_by_link_text('Shift Turnover')

Then I tried several methods of iteration (but I'm just not quite getting it):

elements =

```
search_box.find_elements_by_class_name("plugin_pagetree_children_container")
or
search_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
```

and several others but I'd rather not waste time or confuse the issue.

I should also add this page is a confluence page (if that matters)
... then the loop ...

```
   for e in elements:
      print(e.Text)
      or
      print(e.getText())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT7bd.png)

I'm unclear about which parts of the confluence page are pertinent but here's and example of the source...

''''

```
    <li class="first" >

                        <span class=""><a href="/collector/pages.action?key=Cardians">Dashboard</a></span>
                                                                                                        <li id="ellipsis" title="Show all breadcrumbs"><span><strong>&#8230;</strong></span></li>


    <li class="hidden-crumb" >

                        <span class=""><a href="/display/Cardians/TOC-Card">TOC-Card</a></span>


    <li class="hidden-crumb" >

                        <span class=""><a href="/display/Cardians/Cardians">Cardians</a></span>


    <li class="hidden-crumb" >

                        <span class=""><a href="/display/Cardians/Shift+Turnover">Shift Turnover</a></span>


    <li>

                        <span class=""><a href="/display/Cardians/November+2019+Turnovers">November 2019 Turnovers</a></span>
                                                                </ol>


                </div>


    <a href="#page-banner-end" class="assistive">Skip to end of banner</a>
```

''''

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: can you please share your site or DOM ?

Comment: It's an internal website that can only be reached from inside the company.  (But I would still like to help so is there any other way I could assist?)